# any "official" android app?

Tags: wallets

I've just tried the base program and mist for windows. and wanted to know if there is an "official" sort of app for android. i do not like trusting 3rd parties.

I could try the most popular open source. but core is better.

btw. I tried to google this but those are some hard keywords to find. sorry if this is a duplicate. although it might be good for new people like me.

Whats the most trustworthy way to get etc? coinbase ask all of my data... like that is going to work

Comment: No, there's no official Android app associated with Ethereum.

Answer (score 0):

**[Status](https://status.im/)** is aiming to become the first native mobile dapp browser, however, I believe they are still in beta at the moment.

You can download nightlies here:
**http://artifacts.status.im:8081/artifactory/nightlies-local/**

Answer (score 0):

There are no official android apps which support dapps. But there are quite a few apps that run dapps pretty good.

- [Toshi/Coinbase Wallet](https://www.toshi.org/)
- [Trust Wallet](https://trustwalletapp.com/)
- [Cipher Wallet](https://www.cipherbrowser.com/)

and of course [Status](https://status.im/) which is almost up for mainnet.